# Copy files and put into zip file from batch file or windows command line

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, zip

How can i copy files from another computer in the local network and save them as zip file in my local machine?
Is there a way to zip files directly using xcopy, robocopy or similar programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer from Powershell perspective:**

There are several implementations to zip files with Powershell prior to V5, in V5 there is a cmdlet `compress-archive`.

[Here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/03/15/use-powershell-to-archive-a-folder-and-copy-to-server/) you can find a similiar link to your question (local source, unc dest), but should work the same the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

If powershell is installed on both computers you can just execute the following code.

```
Legit credentials = new credentials.
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName RemotePc -Credential LegitCredentials
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock 
{
 Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
 [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($SourcePath,$destinationPath)
 Move-item from $destinationPath to sharedPath
 Move-item from sharedpath to localpath
}
```